# What different attributes between malloc() and VirtualAlloc() to allocate a memory in windows?

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management

The VirtualAlloc() will allocate a virtual memory page that have some attributes (by the parameter "fdwProtect").

What about the memory that allocated by malloc() ?Is that have same attributes?

Is the memory by malloc() have attributes that "commintting" or "reserving" ?

Further more, what about other C/C++ lib function?

Comment: The memory that malloc() uses was at some point allocated by VirtualAlloc().  If you want to know exactly what attributes the C runtime uses, you could look in the CRT source code.  It will definitely be committed though; only committed memory can be used.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  It sounds like you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Comment: @HarryJohnston thank you for you advice

Comment: @Olaf   sorry . if you were saying that my lastest line,i mean C or C++.  And if you have some understanding about above question,please give some advice ,thanks.

Comment: The functions are C, not C++!

Comment: @Olaf: the meaning seems perfectly clear to me; "are there any such library functions in either C or in C++".  (Well, it isn't clear to me what sort of library functions he wants to know about, but the meaning of "C/C++" seems both clear and logically sound.  I'm not sure what your objection is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.140).aspx)

This function allows you to specify additional options for memory allocation. But it allocates memory in large page with a minimum indicated by [`GetLargePageMinimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366568(v=vs.140).aspx), you can commit, reserve with it. It's not for general use. **Memory allocated by this function is automatically initialized to zero.**

#### malloc

The standard C version to allocate memory. Prefer it if you are writing in C rather than C++, and your code needs to work on on other platforms, or someone specifically says that you need to use it. It's quite possible that, on Windows, `malloc` would be implemented on top of [`HeapAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.140).aspx). `malloc` can allocate any chunk of memory, it doesn't have any concept to commit and reserve by current standard. **Memory allocated by this function is not initialized.**